# How to get the ranges of all the non-matches in the string by regex?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, stl

I have a regular expression and a string. I need to find all the non-matches in the string is a regular expression and get the ranges in the string. 
How can I do this?

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void printNonMatches(const std::regex& re, const std::string& str) {
    const std::string& part;
    size_t start;
    size_t end;

    /* get next non-match */
    /* std::cout << part << " : " << start << ", " << end << std::endl; */
}
```

Comment: How do you define a non-match *string*? Does every match divide the string into [maximum of] two non-match strings?

Comment: Is [this code](https://ideone.com/ZjLs3P) doing what you expect?

Comment: I would like to first get all ranges match the regex, and then get the opposite ranges.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you! That's really what I started doing. But I am not able to get the start and end position of occurrences in the original string.

Comment: To obtain the position may be will take advantage of [std::match_results::position](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/match_results/position/) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

void printNonMatches(const std::regex& r, const std::string& s) {
    size_t lastEndPosition = 0;

    for (std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), r); i != std::sregex_iterator(); ++i) {
        std::smatch m = *i;

        std::cout << s.substr(lastEndPosition, m.position() - lastEndPosition) << " : " << lastEndPosition << ", " << m.position() << std::endl;
        lastEndPosition = m.position() + m.length();
    }
    if (lastEndPosition != s.length())
        std::cout << s.substr(lastEndPosition, s.length() - lastEndPosition) << " : " << lastEndPosition << ", " << s.length()  << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::string s = "My new string";
    std::regex r("\\s+");
    printNonMatches(r, s);
    return 0;
}
```

Live on [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/elu9ZP)